# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xx.xx.' (60)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xx.xx.' (60)
```

I'm getting this error when trying to connect to this server remotely.
I recently hard rebooted my server and I'm guessing I haven't started something I need to.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10

Mysql is up and running. All the sites that use this db are up and running. I can also log into the server and admin the db. But I prefer using a mysql client (navicat) for admin.

Prior to this reboot I was able to connect to this server remotely (navicat) for administration.

I have the appropriate entries in the mysql.user table (as I've said, I was able to connect remotely at one point)

my.cnf file:

```
#skip-external-locking
#bind-address           = 0.0.0.0
```

Any clue as to what might be preventing connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error tells you that client can not reach the server, not that server is not operational. Maybe the address has changed (dhcp?), or port is blocked...

Comment: iptable rule got removed on reboot. not sure how or why but that was it. thanks for your help